# Resize a rectangle element on pinch(gesture)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to crop an image. Inorder to select the crop area I am using an rectangle element.
The initial width and height of the rectangle are set to 100 respectively. On pinch the size of the rectangle will be increased. How can i obtain the size of this rectangle, which is enlarged?

The code I am using is as follows:

```
    private void GestureListener_PinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)  
    {                                                     
         ImageTransformation.ScaleX = _initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;   
         ImageTransformation.ScaleY = ImageTransformation.ScaleX;   
         cropRectangle.Width = cropRectangle.Width + e.DistanceRatio;  
         cropRectangle.Height = cropRectangle.Height + e.DistanceRatio;  
    }
```

I am unable to obtain the size of the enlarged rectangle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderTransforms won't change Width & Height of your Control because it affects only the rendering. Not sure there is a better way but you can simply calculate the render size by using the original size and the scale factor.

Here is a very basic example

**xaml**

```
<Canvas x:Name="cnv" Grid.Row="1">      
    <Rectangle Canvas.Top="150" Canvas.Left="150" 
               Width="200" Height="200" x:Name="myrect" 
               Fill="AliceBlue" 
               ManipulationStarted="myrect_ManipulationStarted" 
               ManipulationDelta="myrect_ManipulationDelta" 
               ManipulationCompleted="myrect_ManipulationCompleted">             
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

**code**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
    translation = new TranslateTransform();
    scale = new ScaleTransform();
    transformGroup.Children.Add(scale);
    transformGroup.Children.Add(translation);
    myrect.RenderTransform = transformGroup;
}

private TransformGroup transformGroup;
private TranslateTransform translation;
private ScaleTransform scale;

private void myrect_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
{
    //change the color of the Rectangle to a half transparent Red
    myrect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(127, 255, 0, 0));
}

private void myrect_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    translation.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
    translation.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;

    //Scale the Rectangle
    if (e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X != 0)
        scale.ScaleX *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
    if (e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y != 0)
        scale.ScaleY *= e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y;

}

private void myrect_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    myrect.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
    Debug.WriteLine(myrect.Width * scale.ScaleX);
    Debug.WriteLine(myrect.Height * scale.ScaleY);
}
```

Comment: I had to multiply with the scale factor,I did a mistake by adding it with distanceratio.Thank you..